# Laravel Optimize developer experience for cron jobs and scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have created a Laravel app and its main functionality is getting data from another API, feeding the Laravel app database tables and as of now, i have achieved so by writing methods inside my controllers and scheduled them in cron commands like

`0 */1 * * * curl https://{app_url}/projects > /dev/null 2>&1`

So there is a controller named `ProjectController` and inside it there is a method called `fetch_data` where i do an HTTP Request to the external API.

How could i do that without the need to run a linux cron job?

I tried with Laravel Jobs but because the tables i feed are about 30 with over 50k rows each, it takes forever to finish. Is there any other option besides Jobs and Http Requests to controllers' methods?

Answer (score 1):

**Queue System with Workers:**
Laravel provides a robust queue system that can help you offload time-consuming tasks to background workers. Instead of running your data-fetching logic directly in your controller or a job, you can dispatch a job to the queue, and then have a worker process the job asynchronously. This can help improve the performance and responsiveness of your application.

Define a new job for fetching data from the external API.
Dispatch this job when needed in your code.
Set up a worker to process jobs in the background.
This way, your application can continue to respond to incoming requests without waiting for the data-fetching task to complete.

Actually you can achieve with Task Scheduling. You have to define the scheduled tasks and set only single cron in the server.

More Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#main-content & https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler